# problems with code formatting on save in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I have vscode installed and also the prettier extension. In settings I select the option format on save. However, when saving the formatting of the code does not happen, I have to activate the format manually. how can I solve that ?

Answer (score 4):

Update, i just find the solution if anyone is having the same problem i have to add the following lines to user setting json

```
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
```

Comment: Not having explicitly set the default formatter was my issue.

Comment: I've tried all of the above and am still unable to get eslint to trigger in my project. If anyone knows anywhere else my settings could be overwritten I'd love the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Press `Ctrl+shift+p` and type `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`. In that json file add the following line and save. This should enable so vscode formats the code each time you save.

```
{
"editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that line is already in the JSON, it was the first thing I checked, the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Have you checked if the workspace settings are overwriting the user settings? Look in Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)

Comment: i did not have warkspace settings defined, i was testing the extencion in a js file located in a new empty folder, i just try creating a workspace json and add the previos meting line to the json to si if it work, but no, same problem

Comment: I have the same issue. Both user and workspace settings have format on save enabled but it does not trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching "reload" in the command palette and the select "Developer: Reload Window" and "JavaScript: Reload Project" options. Hope it helps.